# substr for integer from an array not working in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to use substr for an integer value got from an array, but for some reason it doesn't work. I already used $word[strlen($word)-1],(string), and strval but it still didn't help.

my code goes like this:

```
$word = $marie[$b][1]; // the integer
$nstr = $word[strlen($word)-1];
```

Comment: if you care enough to downvote might as well post your reason. or if you're not great to know the answer might as well post it, or you just dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it isn't a string and the array-accessors for strings only works for strings

```
$word = (string) $word;
$nstr = $word[strlen($word)-1];
```

However, in your case you can (and should) stay in the "integer-world"

```
$nstr = $word % 10;
```

Comment: i see, thank you. i didn't know about that, i've always thought of php to treat variables as strings.

Comment: As soon as it comes to arrays, objects and resources (IO-streams and such) that wouldn't work anymore ;) Internally every variable has a type, but (and thats the type-weakness everybody talks about) if required PHP casts the value to the appropiate type automatically. For example `$a = 'Foo'; if ($a /* interally casted to boolean */) { /* .. */ }`. This (like in your case) doesn't work in every case (`$a = new stdClass; $a = $a + 3;`)

Comment: I see thank you, so when the value for my variable comes from an array it wont always treat it as a string anymore. When would i be able to convert it to string? and how. thank you

Comment: It doesn't matter _where_ the value comes from, but how it is set (e.g. `$a[] = 123'; /* vs. */ $a[] = '123';`). You can always explicitly cast a value like in my example above `(string) $value`.

Comment: so you should cast it before storing it in an array. thank you :) also is there a way for me to negate the first 2 digit? and how?

Comment: @magicianIam What do you mean with "negate the _first two digits_"? If you "negate" them, the whole number is negative. You cannot simply negate _some_ digits :? (BTW: I said earlier "Treat it as an integer" and not "cast it to a string" ;))